# Monthly Summary if Available in List of name and Need to show Monthly total against the Name

Tags: function, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Thanks lot for considering
I have specific list of COdes (ABC, BCD, ......., JKL), Then separately I am maintain the another location with those list of code plus another separate words (Like - Off, ON, .... etc)

So I need to get the Monthly total for Each name, When look make sure to count only the list of codes and Other word need to ignore. Example Need to count only ABC, BCD ,.... In each month.

You can get my example in below G sheet, also Feel Free to contact me for any clarification.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bKA1KOs36ZDfR6VY18Md260MaFJWvO8uY3zto8jscOE/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Sample]

Indika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(C3:C12&"×"&TEXT(D2:O2, "yy-mmm×")&
 XLOOKUP(D3:O12, A3:A, IFERROR(A3:A/0, 1),,,1)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,
your answer working well, but I need to get the summary based on the Month, 
Normally I need to maintain few years information (Like 2021,22,23 Etc.), But in summary I need to get based on the month.

One time I need to get for One year and Other time May be another Year. So need to write formula to get the Information based on the Month, name and count only of list of codes.

Best regard
Indika

Comment: @indikaprasanna try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8rG1.png